# Spring boot application health status down due to Consul

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-consul

My spring boot application's health check status is shown below.

I am not able to debug or generate stack trace. I tried looking for solutions all over the Internet but I found nothing substantial. Please help.

```
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP",
        "total": 250438021120,
        "free": 228222181376,
        "threshold": 10485760
    },
    "db": {
        "status": "UP",
        "database": "MySQL",
        "hello": 1
    },
    "refreshScope": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "hystrix": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "consul": {
        "status": "DOWN",
        "error": "com.ecwid.consul.v1.OperationException: null"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is consul running?

Comment: @spencergibb Yes the consul is running. I am primarily using consul for storing my configurations. The spring-boot application is running fine and is able to pick configurations from the consul. Everything is good except the health check.

Comment: Please add your dependencies and configuration

Comment: also a reproducer would help a lot :)